# "com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException" Appearing on Console

Tags: xml, gwt, console, rpc

I'm trying to make calls from the client side to the server side using RPC and when the web application is set up, the console shows the errors.

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Blocked attempt to access interface 'com.mycompany.project.client.Connection', which is not implemented by 'com.mycompany.project.server.MySQLConnection'; this is either misconfiguration or a hack attempt )

Is there any solution to this because I'm pretty stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gwt-servlet.jar and your gwt-user.jar. It looks like they have different versions.

Comment: May i clarify the both jar file can be found in my reference library where I have added as external jar. In that case how do I check the version for each jar file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the client code making RPC requests is a different version than server code. You may be able to recover by just clearing cache on your browser and forcing it to reload all resources on the page.

If not, here's a ant script I wrote for fully cleaning your project. I use it with all my projects. Modify it to match your project, run it, then run **Project > Clean...** then do a **Java compile**, then a **GWT compile**. Clear the cache on your browser, and see if you still have the problem afterwards.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_HERE" default="clean" basedir=".">

    <target name="clean" description="Cleans this project">
        <!-- <delete dir="war/common" failonerror="false" /> -->
        <!-- <delete dir="war/gwt" failonerror="false" /> -->
        <!-- add more delete tags for whatever modules you may have, just like above -->

        <delete dir="gwt-unitCache" failonerror="false" />
        <delete dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" failonerror="false" />
        <delete dir="war/WEB-INF/deploy" failonerror="false" />
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="." includes="*.war" />
        </delete>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I've done all the above what you have mentioned accordingly but the same error still pops out. 
By the way, my war/Web-Inf file does not consist of a subfolder call "classes" is it normal?

Comment: and as for the XML you have written I would like to ask if it is placed in between the <web-app> .... </web-app>?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to explain the XML bit. Save my XML in a file called `clean.xml` inside your project's root directory. Right click it, Run As > Ant build. The `WEB-INF/classes` directory exists, but Eclipse doesn't show it because it is set as the "output" folder for your project. Sorry to hear it didn't work. Can you also check your "Problems" perspective in Eclipse to see if it shows any GWT SDK version issues?

Comment: Currently, after some amendments, my error now turns to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746360/nullpointerexception-error-when-using-rpc

Comment: @ZhenLiang ok, I will help you there.