# NullPointerException Error when using RPC

Tags: java, gwt, nullpointerexception, gwt-rpc

I'm now currently extracting out data from my database using rpc, but whenever I click the button it does generates a error and my `onFailure` command is being triggered always.

Below is my Code for the program.

```
public class PleaseWork implements EntryPoint {
private TextBox textbox2 = new TextBox();
private Label Hi = new Label("New label");

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

    Button btnNewButton = new Button("New button");

    btnNewButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void onClick(Widget event) {

            HelpConnectionAsync Abra =(HelpConnectionAsync) GWT.create(HelpConnection.class);
            ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) Abra;
            String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
            target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

            AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(){

            public void onSuccess (Object result){
                textbox2.setText((String)result);
                Hi.setText("You Pass!");
            }
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                caught.printStackTrace();
                Hi.setText("You fail!");

            }
            };
            Abra.sensors(callback);
        }
    });

    rootPanel.add(btnNewButton, 23, 30);
    rootPanel.add(textbox2,23, 70);     
    rootPanel.add(Hi, 23, 130);
}
```

}

This consist of both my Async and Service program

```
public interface HelpConnection extends RemoteService {
public String[] sensors() throws Exception;}
public interface HelpConnectionAsync {
public void sensors(AsyncCallback<String[]> callback);}
```

This is my Server side Program

```
public class MySQLConnection extends RemoteServiceServlet implements HelpConnection {
private Connection conn = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/temperature";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "123456";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }

@Override
public String[] sensors() throws Exception {
    String [] user = null;
    try {
          conn = getConnection();

          rs = pstmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID, times FROM sensor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
          // extract data from the ResultSet
          while (rs.next()) {
            user = new String[] {rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2)};
          }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          try {
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
            conn.close();
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        return user;
}}
```

And lastly this is the code generated out by the console

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.lang.NullPointerException_FieldSerializer.instantiate(NullPointerException_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.lang.NullPointerException_FieldSerializer.create(NullPointerException_FieldSerializer.java:25)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:216)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Error on the Development Mode

```
[ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
```

com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Service implementation URL not specified   at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)  at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)     at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)   at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.ServiceDefTarget$NoServiceEntryPointSpecifiedException: Service implementation URL not specified  at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy.doPrepareRequestBuilderImpl(RemoteServiceProxy.java:430)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy.doInvoke(RemoteServiceProxy.java:368)     at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy$ServiceHelper.finish(RemoteServiceProxy.java:74)  at com.mycompany.project.client.HelpConnection_Proxy.sensors(HelpConnection_Proxy.java:30)  at com.mycompany.project.client.PleaseWork$1.onClick(PleaseWork.java:30)    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListenerWrapper$WrappedClickListener.onClick(ListenerWrapper.java:245)     at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:56)  at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)   at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)   at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)     at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)   at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)     at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)  at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)     at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)   at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Another attempt based on changing the return User to return String[] {"text1","text2"}
There was this error genererated in the Developmentmode again,

```
[ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String    at com.mycompany.project.client.PleaseWork$1$1.onSuccess(PleaseWork.java:40)    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)   at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)  at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)   at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: could you, just for a test initialize the  String [] user with some data {"test,"test2"}, and comment out the whole  "try,catch,finally" section? Just to see if the RPC mechanism is created correctly.

Comment: Do you mean by placing a "Random value" as test1 and test 2 and then return this?

Comment: Like @fascynacja said, keep the code, but `return new String[]{"test1", "test2"};` instead of return `return user;` in your server method.

Comment: I am suspecting, that there is some exception in the server code, and therefore you return a null value- which cannot be serialized correctly.

Comment: I have tested already and the above shows the error genereated

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a method

```
public String[] sensors() throws Exception;
```

expecting a return value of String[].

In your call, you handle the return value as String:

```
    AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(){

    public void onSuccess (Object result){
        textbox2.setText((String)result);
        Hi.setText("You Pass!");
    }
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        caught.printStackTrace();
        Hi.setText("You fail!");

    }
    };
```

In fact, it is not a String, it is a String[]. Change your code to:

```
        AsyncCallback<String[]> callback = new AsyncCallback<String[]>(){

        public void onSuccess (String[] result){
            textbox2.setText(result[0]);
            Hi.setText("You Pass!");
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            caught.printStackTrace();
            Hi.setText("You fail!");

        }
        };
```

This will handle the return value correct as String[].

Next thing to improve is your server part:

First, if you catch an exception on the server side, you will not throw it to the client. In your case, you catch the SQLException and proceed as if everything is ok on the server. Adding a throw statement will tell the client, that something went wrong on the server.

```
public String[] sensors() throws Exception {
    String [] user = null;
    try {
          conn = getConnection();

          rs = pstmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID, times FROM sensor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
          // extract data from the ResultSet
          while (rs.next()) {
            user = new String[] {rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2)};
          }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw new MyException();
        } finally {
          try {
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
            conn.close();
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MyException();
          }
        }
        return user;
}}
```

If you don't find something on your DB, yow will return null. You have to check, if your return value is not null before setting the value to the widget.

```
    public void onSuccess (String[] result) {
        if (result != null)
          textbox2.setText(result[0]);
        }
        Hi.setText("You Pass!");
    }
```

I personally prefer using List in this case. Because, you can create the list without knowing, how many values you will return.

Comment: I have changed to what you have suggested but the same error still pops out

Comment: Hava you checked, that your select-statement will return a result? If your result of the db call has zero records, you will get ask a NPE. And: are the ID and times Strings or are they be Integer and Timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're manually setting the `ServiceDefTarget`? If not, can you try this code for your `onModuleLoad()` method?

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
    Button btnNewButton = new Button("New button");
    HelpConnectionAsync Abra =(HelpConnectionAsync) GWT.create(HelpConnection.class);

    btnNewButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void onClick(Widget event) {

            Abra.sensors(new AsyncCallback<String[]>(){

                public void onSuccess (String[] result){
                    if (result == null) {
                        Hi.setText("Result was null!");
                        return;
                    }
                    textbox2.setText(result[0]);
                    Hi.setText("You Pass!");
                }
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    caught.printStackTrace();
                    Hi.setText("You fail!");

                }
            });
        }
    });

    rootPanel.add(btnNewButton, 23, 30);
    rootPanel.add(textbox2,23, 70);     
    rootPanel.add(Hi, 23, 130);
}
```

also, in your server method, in your `catch` blocks, can you catch an `Exception` instead of a `SQLException`? I suspect something escapes.

Comment: I followed most of the examples which I have read hence i placed the ServiceDefTarget. Else I do not know how to configure my Servlet-Mapping (url-pattern)

Comment: This time round when I clicked my button it does not do anything but a error have been generated at my development mode

Comment: @ZhenLiang The new problem is because you have `textbox2.setText((String)result);`. You are trying to cast a `String array` into a `String`. You didn't use any of my code. Use `AsyncCallback<String[]>` like I wrote.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've changed to AsyncCallback<String[]> just that i didn't update the above post

Comment: As for the retrieving of data, I've solved it already, but not sure why. I found out that the error lies within the closing of my PreparedStatement by using system.outprint in each lines and it stops at preparedstatement.close(), hence i use a statement instead of a preparedstatement and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I removed the ServiceDefTarget from your PleaseWork class. It's just a base to work on, now you just have to add you database handling. Also i changed the type of the callback. It now works for me (I removed some code to reduce the amount of code ):

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

    Button btnNewButton = new Button("New button");

    btnNewButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            HelpConnectionAsync Abra = (HelpConnectionAsync) GWT
                    .create(HelpConnection.class);

            AsyncCallback<String[]> callback = new AsyncCallback<String[]>() {

                public void onSuccess(String[] result) {
                    textbox2.setText(result[0]);
                    Hi.setText("You Pass!");
                }

                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    caught.printStackTrace();
                    Hi.setText("You fail!");

                }
            };
            Abra.sensors(callback);

        }
    });
```

In your original post there was no servlet mapping, so i added it :

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("Connection")
public interface HelpConnection extends RemoteService {
public String[] sensors() throws Exception;}
```

And the asyn counterpart :

```
public interface HelpConnectionAsync {
public void sensors(AsyncCallback<String[]> callback);}
```

And the important part of the MySQLConnection :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MySQLConnection extends RemoteServiceServlet implements HelpConnection {


@Override
public String[] sensors() throws Exception {
String [] user = {"test"};
    return user;
}}
```

Besides the Java classes, i used the following web.xml ( /war/WEB-INF/web.xml )

```
    ....
     <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>src.server.MySQLConnection</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/helpconnection/Connection</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ...
```

Also i could not resist to replace the deprecated ClickListener with the not deprecated one.

Comment: Lol, it doesn even return the value of the sample User{test1} the same java null error is poped out at the console

Comment: In Eclipse you can create an exmaple project, does this example work ?

Comment: If i remove all the SQl implmentation and only left with String [] user = {"test"};
    return user;, I'am able to get this.

Comment: But if the SQL implmentation is inside, no doubt i send a sample {test} it does not return any value.